# TEXT to EXCEL - Delimiter

Tags: excel, text, delimiter

hi guys do you know how I can perform text to columns on below data? I can't perform it on excel as the tall box can't be copied to the "other" field of text to columns

[image]

[image]

Comment: PowerQuery has the option to split by custom delimiter and should auto-recognize the [white vertical rectangle](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25AF) (I assumed it's this one). Or use something like `=TEXTSPLIT(A1,UNICHAR(9647))`

Comment: Have you tried the MID() function?

Comment: thanks guys! tried textsplit and mid but does not work either

Comment: It should definitely work. Did you figure out which exact character this is? Try to use `MID()` along with `UNICODE()`. If this does not help, please post sample data as markdown sample data instead of a screenshot.